# mortal kombat console game python2

Tags: python, python-2.7

I just try to make a fighting game that work on console.It's almost finished but I have 2 problem.

1. The game should finish when a user's hp decrease to 1.It doesn't finishing when hp is 0.It gives one more chance to other user.
2. Other one is,after that the game finish,I wanna ask to user "wanna play again?"and if the user says "yes" the game must start before than coin toss.

How can I solve these problems quickly and where is my fault?

```
import random
import time


while True:    
    first_heros_name = raw_input("----- First Hero ----- \n Please type your hero's name: ")
    if len(first_heros_name) > 1:
        print ("First hero's name is", first_heros_name.capitalize())
        break
    else:
        print "Length of hero's name must be longer than 1 character."

while True:    
    second_heros_name = raw_input("----- Second Hero ----- \n Please type your hero's name: ")
    if len(second_heros_name) <= 1:
        print "Length of hero's name must be longer than 1 character."        
    elif second_heros_name == first_heros_name:
        print first_heros_name, "is taken, please choose another name!"

    else:
        print("Second hero's name is"), second_heros_name.capitalize()
        break

players_list = [first_heros_name, second_heros_name]
coin_toss = random.choice(players_list)
players_list.remove(coin_toss)
print "Coin toss result: %s starts first!" %coin_toss #Coin toss result
print "The game begins in 5 seconds!" #countdown
##time.sleep(1)
##print "---4---"
##time.sleep(1)
##print "---3---"
##time.sleep(1)
##print "---2---"
##time.sleep(1)
##print "---1---"
##time.sleep(1)



def attack1(current_hp):
    hp2=current_hp
    chance_of_damaging=random.randint(0,100)
    print "--------------- %s Attacks !! ---------------"%coin_toss
    while True:
        attack_magnitute=input("Choose your attack magnitude between 1 and 50: ")

        if attack_magnitute > 50:
            print "The attack magnitude must be between 1 and 50."

        elif attack_magnitute < 1:
            print "The attack magnitude must be between 1 and 50."
        else:
            break


    while True:
        if chance_of_damaging > attack_magnitute:
            print coin_toss, " hits %s damage!!"%attack_magnitute
            hp2=hp2-attack_magnitute
            return hp2
        else:
            print "Ooopsy! %s missed the attack!"%coin_toss
            return hp2

def attack2(current_hp):
    hp1=current_hp
    chance_of_damaging=random.randint(0,100)
    print "--------------- %s Attacks !! ---------------"%players_list
    while True:
        attack_magnitute=input("Choose your attack magnitude between 1 and 50: ")

        if attack_magnitute > 50:
            print "The attack magnitude must be between 1 and 50."

        elif attack_magnitute < 1:
            print "The attack magnitude must be between 1 and 50."
        else:
            break


    while True:
        if chance_of_damaging > attack_magnitute:
            print players_list, " hits %s damage!!"%attack_magnitute
            hp1=hp1-attack_magnitute
            return hp1
        else:
            print "Ooopsy! %s missed the attack!"%players_list
            return hp1

def main():
    hp1, hp2 = (100,100)
    while hp2<=1:
        print players_list, " win"
        break

    while hp1 > 1 and hp2 > 1:
            hp1 = attack1(hp1)
            print coin_toss,"                                                                 ", players_list

            print "HP [%s]:"%hp2, hp2/2 * "|" ,"        ", "HP [%s]:"%hp1, hp1/2 * "|" 
            hp2 = attack2(hp2)
            print coin_toss,"                                                                 ", players_list

            print "HP [%s]:"%hp2, hp2/2 * "|" ,"        ", "HP [%s]:"%hp1, hp1/2 * "|"

    while hp1<=1:
        print coin_toss, " win"
        break





main()
```

Comment: tag `PyGame` is for question of `PyGame` module but you don't use it.

Comment: sorry I fixed it.

Comment: instead of `while ... break` you should use `if`.

Comment: I tried it but it is still giving a chance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you have to check `hp1` before you second player makes move.
2. You have to put it in `while` loop which will: set `hp` to `100`, run game, ask if you want ot play again.

I made other changes

- `attack1` and `attack2` were almost identical so I create one function `attack()` with more parameters.
- you ask for magnitute in two places so I create function `ask_magnitute()`
- you display result in two places so I create function `display()`
- you ask for player in two places so I create function `ask_name()`

Code with other changes

```
import random
import time

# --- functions ---

def ask_for_magnitute():
    while True:
        value = input("Choose your attack magnitude between 1 and 50: ")

        if value > 50:
            print "The attack magnitude must be between 1 and 50."
        elif value < 1:
            print "The attack magnitude must be between 1 and 50."
        else:
            return value


def attack(points, name):

    chance_of_damaging = random.randint(0, 100)

    print "---------------", name, "Attacks !! ---------------"

    attack_magnitute = ask_for_magnitute()

    if chance_of_damaging > attack_magnitute:
        print name, "hits", attack_magnitute, "damage!!"
        points -= attack_magnitute
    else:
        print "Ooopsy!", name, "missed the attack!"

    return points


def display(points1, points2, name1, name2):
    print name1, "                                                                 ", name2
    print "HP [%s]:" % points2, points2/2 * "|" ,"        ",  # comma at the end and it doesn't add `"\n"`
    print "HP [%s]:" % points1, points1/2 * "|" 


def ask_name(text, other_heros_list):
    while True:
        print '-----', text, 'Hero -----'

        name = raw_input("Please type your hero's name: ")
        name = name.capitalize()

        if len(name) <= 1:
            print "Length of hero's name must be longer than 1 character."        
        elif name in other_heros_list:
            print name, "is taken, please choose another name!"
        else:
            print text, "hero's name is", name
            break

    return name


def main():

    players_list = []

    hero_name = ask_name("First", players_list)
    players_list.append(hero_name)

    hero_name = ask_name("Second", players_list)
    players_list.append(hero_name)

    random.shuffle(players_list)

    coin_toss = players_list[0]
    player    = players_list[1] 

    print "Coin toss result: %s starts first!" % coin_toss #Coin toss result
    print "The game begins in 5 seconds!" #countdown

    # --- loop ----

    running = True

    while running:

        # --- init --- 

        # (re)set points
        hp1, hp2 = (100, 100)

        # --- game ---

        while hp1 > 1 and hp2 > 1:
            hp1 = attack(hp1, coin_toss)
            display(hp1, hp2, coin_toss, player)

            if hp1 <= 1:
                break

            hp2 = attack(hp2, player)
            display(hp1, hp2, coin_toss, player)

        # --- game over ---

        if hp1 <= 1:
            print coin_toss, " win"
        if hp2 <= 1:
            print player, " win"

        # --- play again ---

        answer = raw_input('Play again [Y/n]?').lower().strip()

        # exit only if `n` - other answers starts again  
        if answer == 'n':
            running = False

# --- main ---

main()
```

Comment: I add function `ask_name()` because this part of code was similar for boths player.

Comment: Thank you so much,it is working very well but there is one more problem.I uploaded the image of problem.When it show the results it display "[x , y] win.
Here the image https://ibb.co/mixCX6

Comment: I solved it.I changed the "players_list" to "player" in "game over" part.Thank you so much again.

Comment: I made many changes on my computer and forgot to put `player` instead of `players_list` in code on SO. :)